# convert text into a javascript object or array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi i have a set of words that's retrieved by php and displayed on two hidden text field like this:

**The titles:**

```
Red Apple, Grapes, Green Apple, Orange
```

**The file names:**

```
red_apple5, grapes1, green_apple2, orange3
```

is there a way that i can convert this to an object or array something like this:

```
T = {"Red Apple" , "Grapes" , "Green Apple" , "Orange"}

S = {"red_apple5" , "grapes1" , "green_apple2" , "orange3"}
```

i want append each of them to a list. is there a way to do this?

Comment: `{"Red Apple" , "Grapes" , "Green Apple" , "Orange"}` - it is syntactically incorrect

Comment: Correct, curly braces ("{" or "}") notate an Object, which is a set of key: value pairs. EX: {name: "John", city: "compton"}. Square brackets notate arrays. EX ["one", "two", "three"]. Good reference found here: http://godbit.com/article/js-tidbits-datatypes-object-object-vs-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to create a valid object, utilize the following code for reference. *NOTE: Some modifications were made for illustrative purposes.*

**HTML**:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
var titles = 'Red Apple, Grapes, Green Apple, Orange'.split(', ');
var fileNames = 'red_apple5, grapes1, green_apple2, orange3'.split(', ');

var newObject = {};

for(var i=0; i < titles.length; i++){
    newObject [titles[i]] = fileNames[i];
}

$('#output').text(JSON.stringify(newObject));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GHgsT/

The code above loops through the `titles` array and then maps the `titles[index]` value as the object's property (key) and the corresponding `fileNames[index]` value as the property's value.

Comment: It is always better to beautify the code with `JSON.stringify` http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/vjTFk/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = 'Red Apple, Grapes, Green Apple, Orange'.split(', ');
```

Comment: What about `S` (the other object `file names`)

Comment: @Derek: I don't get you. I'm sure OP could understand that he may apply `.split()` to any string so I don't need to give example for every single sting in the world

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript's split() method to split the string:

```
var str = "Red Apple, Grapes, Green Apple, Orange";
var arr = str.split(', ');
console.log(arr)
```

To append these to a list, you must loop through the newly created array using forEach() and then create a new li for each item. Then you can append the li as a child element to a ul.

```
var list = document.getElementById("#IdOfYourList")
arr.forEach(function(a) {
    var newLi = document.createElement("li")
    newLi.innerHTML = a;
    list.appendChild(newLi);
});
```

Also note that forEach is not supported in IE < 8, but can be implemented into the Array prototype here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 1):

Use [.split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

```
var str = "Red Apple, Grapes, Green Apple, Orange";
var array = str.split(", ");
```